# Temporarily disabling scrolling on touchmove (mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I've been searching the net for several days now and have not found a solution to my problem. I'm building a mobile site and on it there will be elements which can be horizontally scrolled by swiping your finger over them. So far this works fine.

To prevent the page from being scrolled vertically while swiping I added the event.preventDefault() to the touchmove event, and here's the problem; I want the user to be able to scroll the page while swiping this element vertically, but only if he/she swiped it for, lets say 60 pixels (vertically). How can I do this? With the code I used, the "else" (when the scroll-length is more than 70px) is executed, but no scrolling happens. Is what I want to do even possible, and in that case how?

Here's some code with what I've tried:

```
$(Carousel_Wrapper).bind('touchstart', function(event) 
{
    // Some other stuff happens here

    // Set last y-coord
    Carousel_LastPageY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

    // Bind the touchmove event
    $(Carousel_Wrapper).bind('touchmove', function(event) 
    {
        // The function which scrolls the content of the element
        Carousel_Drag(event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX, event);

        // Calculate the vertical swipe length
        var Carousel_VerticalSwipeLength = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY - Carousel_LastPageY;

        // Convert to a positive value
        if(Carousel_VerticalSwipeLength < 0)
        {
            Carousel_VerticalSwipeLength = Carousel_VerticalSwipeLength * -1;
        }

        // If the vertical scroll-length is less than 70px
        if(Carousel_VerticalSwipeLength < 70)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        // The scroll-length was more than 70px, resume scrolling
        else
        {
            // I've tried this:
            return true;

            // Then this:
            $(Carousel_Wrapper).unbind('touchmove');

            // And at last this:
            $(Carousel_Wrapper).unbind('touchmove');
            $(Carousel_Wrapper).trigger('touchmove');
        }
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Henrik

Answer (score 0):

Your variable should store the summation of the differences in the touches. Your variable looks like it only looks at the amount of each differential, not the sum of them.

Comment: So you mean that the else (where the scroll-length is more than 70px) is not being triggered? In fact I've tried that by writing to a temporary element the distance of the vertical swipe (from the else), and it checks out, its being executed. Please correct me if that's not what you meant